# Recursion method

Tags: javascript

Something's not working with this method. Where's the error?

find the Odd numbers:

```js
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

```js
function findOddNum(array) {
  let result = [];
  let i = 0;

  function helper_func(inputArray) {
    if (inputArray.length === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    if (inputArray[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      result = inputArray[i];
    }
    i++;
    helper_func(array);
  }
  helper_func(array);
  return result;
}
const res = findOddNum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);

console.log(res);
```

It returns the following error:

```
maximum call stack size not exceeded
```

Comment: You have infinite recursion because you unconditionally call the `helper_func` function for non-empty `inputArray`s. Do you expect the length to somehow change? You’re only changing `i`. Why are you using recursion to find odd numbers?

Comment: Amaan, You should use `English` language to explain your question. Most people don't understand `Hindi`, If they can't understand your problem then surely they can't answer it.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't added the nested function termination condition

```
if (i >= inputArray.length) return;
```

Without termination condition, it will go infinite recursion. That's the reason it gives you `maximum call stack size not exceeded`

```js
function findOddNum(array) {
  let result = [];
  let i = 0;

  function helper_func(inputArray) {
    if (i >= inputArray.length) return; // change
    if (inputArray.length === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    if (inputArray[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      result.push(inputArray[i]);
    }
    i++;
    helper_func(array);
  }
  helper_func(array);
  return result;
}
const res = findOddNum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);

console.log(res);
```

BTW You don't have to use recursion just to get the odd numbers, It is one liner solution

```
array.filter((num) => num % 2)
```

```js
function findOddNum(array) {
  return array.filter((num) => num % 2);
}
const res = findOddNum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: thanks bro i m learner. So i practice DSA

Comment: Not a problem, we all are learners like you. Would you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer if it solved your issue?

Comment: Yes ofcourse @decpk. hope you allow me to asking questions with you

Comment: sure why not but instead of asking questions here in the comment section, It would be better to ask questions in Stackoverflow(SOF) directly. Here it could be possible that only some people know about or get to know when someone comment.

Answer (score 0):

in case of recursion you need to give a base condition (termination condition), else it would go in an infinite loop

add the below line in helper_func

```
if(i>=inputArray.length)
    return false;
```

```js
function findOddNum(array) {
  let result = [];
  let i = 0;

  function helper_func(inputArray) {
    if (inputArray.length === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    if(i>=inputArray.length){
       return false;
    }
    if (inputArray[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      result = inputArray[i];
    }
    i++;
    helper_func(array);
  }
  helper_func(array);
  return result;
}
const res = findOddNum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);

console.log(res);
```